# Problems with mysql connection in typescript

Tags: mysql, typescript, visual-studio

I have my bbdd defined here:

```
export default{

database: {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    dabatase: 'nominas'
  }
}
```

I attempt to do the connection in another file:

```
import mysql, { Connection } from 'promise-mysql';

import keys from './keys';


const pool = mysql.createConnection(keys.database);


pool.getConnection(any)
  .then (Connection => {
    pool.releaseConnection(Connection);
    console.log('DB is connected');
});

export default pool;
```

The problem is that the createConnection function returns a value type: Bluebird, and I cann't do functions like releaseConnection, and getConnection on it, and not add, update or list bbdd data. Can anybody help me? I'm using the latest version of visual studio code and typescript.